# Tesseract in R not recognizing "&"

Tags: r, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I am a beginner in R programming and a supposed to write a code to read in text from images!
I am using the Tesseract and Magick packages for doing the same and am facing an issue where the code converts an "&" to "8:"
I have attached the image that I am using as an input. [Image used for processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn9nW.jpg)

Below is the code that I am running

```
test2 <- image_read("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/testimage.jpg") %>%
  image_resize("2000") %>%
  image_convert(colorspace = 'gray') %>%
  image_trim() %>%
  image_ocr()
cat(test2)
write.table(test2, "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/output2.txt", sep="\t")
```

Below is the output that I am getting

```
No relation between boycotting
panchayat polls 8: Article 35A:
Subramanian Swamy
```

I have referred to the [following](https://www.r-bloggers.com/tesseract-and-magick-high-quality-ocr-in-r/) source to gain some understanding but did not find any suitable solution for this specific problem.

I have also gone through this website but did not find much help in reading in special characters.

If someone can help me, that would be really helpful.

Comment: You can file an issue here in case you don't get any answer https://github.com/ropensci/tesseract/issues

Comment: In the command line version of tesseract, I created a separate text file with just an `&` in it, and then passed it to the `--user-words` option, and that accurately read the `&`. Not quite sure how to pass that option in R though

Comment: That full command is `tesseract /path/to/image.png --user-words path/to/&file.txt out`

Comment: if i add `"&:"` to the whitelist it is read as an `8`, but if i use `";&"` it reads the ampersand. But of course the `"35A:"` is now `"35A;"`

Comment: @user20650 when you say that you are adding ";&" in the whitelist, what exactly do you mean? I added the following line to the command and the result is still the same:- `engine <- tesseract(options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = ";&"))` **This line is used between the image_ocr option and the cat(test) line**

Comment: yup, I did, `wl = paste(paste(letters, LETTERS, collapse="", sep=""), "0123456789&;") ; engine <- tesseract(options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = wl), cache=FALSE) ; 
text <- ocr("https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn9nW.jpg", engine) ; 
cat(text) ` . I have an issue with the fonts though - `t` getting read as `l`

Comment: @user20650 thank you for taking out the time. I used the code you mentioned but the result is still the same :(

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Imagemagick with a TIF instead of a JPG to do the same ?
I used the below query and it worked.

```
test20 <- image_read("E:/xx/image.tif") %>%
image_resize("4000") %>%
image_convert(colorspace = 'gray') %>%
image_trim() %>%
image_ocr()
cat(test20)
write.table(test2, "E:/xx/output.txt", sep="\t")
```